# How do I parse a .net DataSet in Java?

Tags: java, android, .net, dataset

I am sending a simple soap request to a .net webservice.  However the response returned is a .net dataset.  Is it possible to read a .net DataSet in java?
Below is the soap request I am using and how I am trying to read the response:

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //Set up request
    request.addProperty("Account", "****");  //Variable name, value.  
    request.addProperty("Name", "****");
    request.addProperty("Password", "****");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); //Prepare the request
    HttpTransportSE HttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL); 
    HttpTransport.debug = true;

    HttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //Send Request
    SoapObject result = null;
    result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

    result.toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done some more research this question is answered on this site already:

[Parsing a .NET DataSet returned from a .NET Web Service in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667646/parsing-a-net-dataset-returned-from-a-net-web-service-in-java/2706507#2706507)

Answer (score 2):

You should use soap service like below.

> SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new  SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
>     soapEnvelope.dotNet=true;//to handle .net services asmx/aspx

for more reference visit [Android and .NET Webservice - parsing the returned xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462399/android-and-net-webservice-parsing-the-returned-xml)