# How can change task percent complete in project server programmatically?

Tags: wsdl, wsdl2java, ms-project, ms-project-server-2010, psi

I want to develop a client code in Java (C# api was useful till now) to change task status in a project in MS Project Server. Using wsdl I can read project entities, but I couldn,t find a way to change a task "complete percent". 
I have two questions.

1. Which method can help me? Is it in "PWA/_vti_bin/PSI/Project.asmx?wsdl" ? Is "queueUpdateProject()" the right method?
2. How should I compose the request xml?

Any api or guide in Java or C# could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project Server communicates with PSI clients using ADO.NET Datasets. The structure isn't standard for Java and I don't know any good implementation of the Datasets in Java. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667646/parsing-a-net-dataset-returned-from-a-net-web-service-in-java/2706507#2706507).

I agree with propose solution for that question: create proxy web service which will translate your objects serialized in Java to the .NET datasets.

The overall workflow looks like this:

- CheckOutProject
- QueueAddToProject (adds tasks, resources, assignments)
- QueueDeleteFromProject (drops tasks, resources, assignments)
- QueueUpdateProject (updates tasks, resources, assignments, adds/drops/updates enterprise custom fields), Does not access > 1000 records per call
- QueuePublishProject (optional)
- QueueCheckInProject

All documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcproject.project_di_pj14mref_methods.aspx